# How to build a banded matrix on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to build the banded matrix

```
C = [-1 1 ... 0]
    [ -1 1 ....]
    [..........]
    [0.....-1 1]
```

I managed to create a different banded matrix with

```
spdiags(ones(nx,1)*[1 -2 1],-1:1,nx,nx)
```

which looks like this:

```
C = [-2  1 ... 0]
    [ 1 -2 .....]
    [......... 1]
    [0..... 1 -2]
```

However, if I change `[1 -2 1]` to `[-1 1]`, it doesn't work.

I get the error message

```
>> spdiags(ones(nx,1)*[-1 1],-1:1,nx,nx)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in spdiags (line 102)
         a((len(k)+1):len(k+1),:) = [i i+d(k) B(i+(m>=n)*d(k),k)];
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: _"I didn't manage to implement it"_ and _"it doesn't work"_ are not appropriate error descriptions. Your example matrix `C` is not a banded matrix, either. Did you mean `[0....-1 1]` for the last row?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. I also updated to include the error message

Comment: That is not the error message. I'll propose an edit for your question.

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using for `[-1 1]`, the actual results and the full desired results. Are you expecting a non-square matrix? How did you change the second (and maybe third) parameters to `spdiags`?

Comment: @beaker The question already contains all of that.

Comment: @dasdingonesin No, you edited in your assumption of what the OP intended.

Comment: @beaker Which is why the question contains all of that.

Comment: @dasdingonesin That doesn't make it correct. I asked the OP what they intended, not what you think they intended.

Comment: @beaker: I told OP I was going to propose an edit, I proposed an edit, the OP accepted the edit, which means the question now asks what the OP wanted to ask. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @dasdingonesin Making/Proposing that edit was definitely wrong. In case if OP's intention was different and it had gone in the review queue and got approved, your edit would've harmed the question. Fortunately it didn't happen. For the cases where you believe that you have understood the intent of the post, better post the answer and if the OP accepts it, you're good to go edit the post. Otherwise, it's really a bad idea

Comment: @dasdingonesin You're right, the OP did accept the edit, which I missed. It is not immediately apparent who approved an edit unless you go looking for it. You got me. Your edit still does not specify the dimensions of the desired output (square or not) and it removes attribution for the source of the OP's code.

Comment: @SardarUsama I see. I'll follow that approach next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`doc spdiags`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) will tell you, the second argument of `spdiags` specifies the diagonals that will be replaced in your matrix. As you want to modify different diagonals, you'll have specify those.

This will do what you want:

```
>> nx = 5;
>> C = spdiags(ones(nx,1)*[-1 1],0:1,nx,nx+1);
>> full(C)

ans =

    -1     1     0     0     0     0
     0    -1     1     0     0     0
     0     0    -1     1     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     1     0
     0     0     0     0    -1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

A slighty more convoluted approach:

```
n = 5;                                   % desired number of columns
p = [-1 1];                              % pattern for each row
C = conv2(eye(n), flip(p), 'valid').';   % result
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's two pretty quick methods (although your approach could be sped up by removing the matrix multiplication).

---

You could just use a simple combination of `eye` (to create the diagonals) and `zeros` (to pad the extra column) to get the desired result:

```
nx = 5;
C = [-eye(nx), zeros(nx,1)] + [zeros(nx,1), eye(nx)];

% C = -1     1     0     0     0     0
%      0    -1     1     0     0     0
%      0     0    -1     1     0     0
%      0     0     0    -1     1     0
%      0     0     0     0    -1     1
```

---

Or use `diag` to create an offset diagonal, and subtract an `eye` matrix, you would need to removed the last row though. This gives the same result:

```
C = diag(ones(nx,1),1) - eye(nx+1);
C = C(1:end-1, :);
```